# Kohana ORM: How to query for a timestamp that's calculated based on a field in the DB

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, orm, kohana

Simple table:

```
start_date       TIMESTAMP
duration_days    INT
```

In English: I simply want the rows which have not passed their `duration` period.

In SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE now() < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, duration_days, start_date);
```

How can I do this in Kohana/ORM? The duration is different for each of many rows I need to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `where()` clause:

```
ORM::factory('MyTable')->where(DB::expr('now()'), '<', DB::expr('TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, duration_days, start_date)'))->find_all();
```